# How to turn off 'dead' single and double quotation keys in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I am having some trouble with Pycharm, when I press the single quote key, on the first press, nothing happens, on the second press Pycharm writes two single quotations. On the third press, nothing happens, on the fourth press, voila! two more single quotes. Double quotes exhibit the same behavior.

This makes typing triple-quotes for strings in Python quite maddening. I would like to get one character for one key press... like every other key on this keyboard.

This is only happening in Pycharm Community Edition and not any other text-editing software on this Windows machine.

I have played with every relevant looking setting in Pycharm's settings without success.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference:

Check if the Windows language setting is set to US Intl Keyboard. If it is, switch to a US keyboard (may have to add keyboard if necessary). It should be fine then. No idea why that's the case as well.

Comment: For anyone that applied this solution and would still occasionally have Windows decide to revert back to "dead single/ double quotation keys" try this:

Settings > Time & Language > Language > Keyboard

check if "override for default input method" is set to anything other than your desired keyboard setting. For my it was set to: "use language list (recommended)".

Comment: Additionally, when in  Settings > Time & Language > Language > Keyboard there is a link: "Input language hot keys". I have disabled all the hotkeys so it doesn't change back when I press Ctrl+Shift or Alt+Shift (it changed between these combination without my input.............).